How to upload files with Django and Python
I want to let the user upload some excel files, and first im trying to save them in the media/uploaded/int:projectid (that i want to create if its not created already).
But when i try to upload it, in the /admin it says:
Error in field "template_file": This field is required.
Error in field "title": This field is required.
this is my views.py:
@csrf_protect
@login_required(login_url='login')
def uploadTemplate(request, proyecto_id):
    proyecto = get_object_or_404(Project, id=proyecto_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadTemplateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            template_file = request.FILES.get('template_file')
            if template_file:
                try:
                    create_project_folder(proyecto)  # Crear la carpeta del proyecto si no existe
                    handle_uploaded_file(template_file, proyecto)
                    messages.success(request, 'File uploaded successfully.')
                    return redirect('success')
                except Exception as e:
                    messages.error(request, f'Error handling the file: {e}')
            else:
                messages.error(request, 'No file provided in the form.')
        else:
            for field, errors in form.errors.items():
                for error in errors:
                    messages.error(request, f'Error in field "{field}": {error}')
    else:
        form = UploadTemplateForm()
    return render(request, 'uploadFileBox.html', {'form': form, 'project': proyecto})

def create_project_folder(proyecto):
    base_folder = 'media/uploaded'
    project_folder = os.path.join(base_folder, str(proyecto.id))
    if not os.path.exists(project_folder):
        os.makedirs(project_folder)

def handle_uploaded_file(f, proyecto):
    try:
        base_folder = 'media/uploaded'
        project_folder = os.path.join(base_folder, str(proyecto.id))
        file_path = os.path.join(project_folder, f.name)
        with open(file_path, 'wb+') as destination:
            for chunk in f.chunks():
                destination.write(chunk)
        print("Archivo guardado correctamente.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error al manejar el archivo:", e)

my uploadFileBox.html:
<form id="uploadForm" action="{% url 'uploadFile' project.id %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="file-input" type="file" name="template_file" accept=".xls, .xlsx">
                      <svg width="50%" height="50%" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path d="M14 11H8M10 15H8M16 7H8M20 6.8V17.2C20 18.8802 20 19.7202 19.673 20.362C19.3854 20.9265 18.9265 21.3854 18.362 21.673C17.7202 22 16.8802 22 15.2 22H8.8C7.11984 22 6.27976 22 5.63803 21.673C5.07354 21.3854 4.6146 20.9265 4.32698 20.362C4 19.7202 4 18.8802 4 17.2V6.8C4 5.11984 4 4.27976 4.32698 3.63803C4.6146 3.07354 5.07354 2.6146 5.63803 2.32698C6.27976 2 7.11984 2 8.8 2H15.2C16.8802 2 17.7202 2 18.362 2.32698C18.9265 2.6146 19.3854 3.07354 19.673 3.63803C20 4.27976 20 5.11984 20 6.8Z" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                      </svg>
                      
                      <p>Browse files to upload</p>
                  </form>

urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',views.SignupPage, name='signup'),
    path('login/',views.LoginPage, name='login'),
    path('home/',views.HomePage,name='home'),
    path('logout/',views.LogoutPage,name='logout'),
    path('home/create/', views.createProject, name='createProject'),
    path('projects/',views.viewProjects,name='viewProjects'),
    path('projects/<int:project_id>/information', views.projectDetail, name='projectDetail'),
    path('projects/<int:proyecto_id>/members/', views.projectMembers, name='projectMembers'),
    path('static/Templates/', views.downloadTemplate, name='downloadTemplate'),
    path('delete-project/<int:project_id>/', views.deleteProject, name='deleteProject'),
    path('projects/<int:proyecto_id>/upload-file/', views.uploadTemplate, name='uploadFile')
    # path('projects/<int:project-id/dashboard>',views.X, name='dashboard')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


I tried to upload a file from the user perspective, and it wont work

Apparently, the definition of UploadTemplateForm has template_file and title as required fields, and your uploadFileBox.html does not provide those fields.

It might help if you showed the definition of UploadTemplateForm.

From your code, since you have an UploadTemplateForm, why not just use it?
